# (parameter) e:any error in React typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[image: 1]

The error says `(parameter)e:any` and doesn't compile, I tried changing it to `('submit', e:any)` but that didn't work either, and says

> any refers to a type, but it is being used as a value here.

How do I simply pass `e` into `addEventListener`?

Comment: (e:any) instead of e:any

Answer (score 1):

You should have included a full example of what you're trying, but judging by your description, you're probably setting the type of `e` incorrectly. Try this:

```
form2.addEventListener('submit', (e: any) => {
  // your function here
});
```

It looks like you're trying

```
form2.addEventListener('submit', e:any) =>
```

In that case, please keep in mind that [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) takes two parameters in this case:

- the event type (`submit`),
- and a function (`e => { ... }`). So you must set the parameter in said function so it becomes (`(e: any) => {...}`), and that's how we arrive to the aforementioned solution.